# Where does Elasticsearch store its data?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

So I have this Elasticsearch installation, in insert data with logstash, visualize them with kibana.

Everything in the conf file is commented, so it's using the default folders which are relative to the elastic search folder.

```
1/ I store data with logstash
2/ I look at them with kibana
3/ I close the instance of elastic seach, kibana and logstash
4/ I DELETE their folders
5/ I re-extract everything and reconfigure them
6/ I go into kibana and the data are still there
```

How is this possible?

This command will however delete the data : `curl -XDELETE 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_all'`

Thanks.

ps : forgot to say that I'm on windows

Comment: Did  you try to access Kibana from an incognito window in Chrome for example? It might be the browser's cache that is retrieved when you search for the data.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you've installed ES on Linux, the [default data folder](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-dir-layout.html#default-paths) is in `/var/lib/elasticsearch` (CentOS) or `/var/lib/elasticsearch/data` (Ubuntu)

If you're on Windows or if you've simply extracted ES from the ZIP/TGZ file, then you should have a `data` sub-folder in the extraction folder.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, I have a data folder, however kibana still display the data even after deletion of this data folder

Comment: On what system are you? Linux or Windows? And how did you delete the ES folder?

Comment: I go to the "project' folder which contains the "elasticsearch-1.7.2" folder, right clic and erase it (and yes, I stopped the elastic search instance before

Comment: you are right, but my problem was in fact because we were several people on the network running the same conf and our data were shared. 3 years later, I know :p

Comment: On Elastic Search 7 on Ubuntu, the path is also /var/lb/elasticsearch

Answer (score 21):

Have a look into the [Nodes Stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html) and try

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/_nodes/stats/fs?pretty
```

On Windows 10 with ElasticSearch 7 it shows:

```
"path" : "C:\\ProgramData\\Elastic\\Elasticsearch\\data\\nodes\\0"
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/setup-dir-layout.html) the data is stored in a folder called "data" in the elastic search root directory.

Comment: Yes, but the data are still present event after deletion of elastic search root directory

Comment: You are probably running into a cache at that point. The delete command you are sending using CURL would be the proper way to handle this.

Comment: This is just about curiosity, where is this cache? since I erased everything.
Does it store something in appdata?

Answer (score 5):

If you run the Windows MSI installer (at least for 5.5.x), the default location for data files is:

```
C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\data
```

The `config` and `logs` directories are siblings of `data`.

Answer (score 3):

Elastic search is storing data under the folder 'Data' as mentioned above answers.
Is there any other elastic search instance available on your local network?
If yes, please check the cluster name. If you use same cluster name in the same network it will share data.

Refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/important-settings.html) link for more info.

Answer (score 1):

On centos:

```
/var/lib/elasticsearch
```

Comment: that was already answered in 2015

Answer (score 0):

It should be in your extracted elasticsearch. Something like es/data