# Where does elasticsearch store its data on filesystem

Tags: elasticsearch

I am relatively new to elasticsearch, and I was wondering where does Elasticsearch store its records. I installed Elasticsearch on `/var/lib/elasticsearch`, and see index being created in this directory. For example, an index

> logstash-2016.11.11

creates

> /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2016.11.11

I also set replication to 1 so that each record will have two copies.

Later on I deleted the `/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes` folder, and rerun elasticseach again, but find out interestingly the old record still exist with just one copy.

Is Elasticsearch storing the copy somewhere else? Where can I find the other copies. Thank you.

Comment: which version of elastic search are you using?

Comment: what is there in `/var/lib/elasticsearch/data` directory ?

Comment: I do not have that folder, in /var/lib/elasticsearch, I have only lost+found/ and nodes/

Comment: Hi,
When you install elasticsearch you have created data directory somewhere,
Try to remember where you created this directory, the data is there

Comment: Replicas must be stored on other instance (server)

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303786/where-does-elastic-search-store-its-data/33303945#33303945

Comment: @Val As i see he is looking for copy (Replicas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on configuration but to find location of your data you can look to:

1. look firstly to [default folder structure](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/setup-dir-layout.html)
2. Look [to configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/setup-configuration.html) elasticsearch.yml and search for path

Replicas is a bit different

When you set replica to 1 it means that it will be stored as copy but not on the same instance. One instance is storing shards (Part of data), but **replicas must go to other instance**(Its because if your main server crashed you have one more copy of your data). So if you have one server it means that you will **not have 2 copies** of your data. And cluster status will be yellow since your data are not replicated

Comment: I'm using Elasticsearch 5.5 and in my "C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch" there is no folder named data. I've looked in the documentation there is no mention of such data files. I need to transfer my data from old laptop to new laptop. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look into the [Nodes Stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html) and try

```
http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats/fs?pretty
```

On Windows 10 with ElasticSearch 7 it shows:

```
"path" : "C:\\ProgramData\\Elastic\\Elasticsearch\\data\\nodes\\0"
```